# Error : execution time for the action exceeded .. secs. In PHP only on Linux

Tags: timeout, php

I am facing an Error :

> execution time for the action exceeded .. secs.

In PHP. I am using `set_time_limit(0);`

And it is working fine on windows. But it is not working on linux.

Comment: Please post some code around the line where the error occurs.

Comment: Beyond queries, are you making any other blocking calls?

Answer (score 1):

See here :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

> This function has no effect when PHP
>   is running in safe mode. There is no
>   workaround other than turning off safe
>   mode or changing the time limit in the
>   php.ini.

are you in safe mode ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because the host PHP doesn't allow you to override their settings. Remember, set_time_limit() overrides a default. Its something you might want to take up with your host (or, perhaps, see if you can speed things up).

`phpinfo()` should tell you, either way. Safe mode or [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) would explain it.

**NB**: *I have no idea if you are making blocking calls that would be fine on Windows but problematic on Linux. A little debug output, or snips of code around the point where it stalls would be helpful. It could be that set_time_limit() has no influence on proper behavior on Windows. Without code, its hard to say :)*